# What file formats does AutodeskForge support?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I would like to want to know the list of file formats supported by Autodesk Forge.

The list can be confirmed on the following two sites.

1. https://viewer.autodesk.com (click the link called "2D and 3D formats")
2. https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations/

However, there is contradiction between these two sites.

The following file formats are listed only in "1.".

DDX,
DDZ,
DGK,
DMT,
OSB,
PAR,
PSM,
SMB,
SMT,
VPB

On the other hand, the following file formats are listed only in "2.".

F2D,
PDF,
RCP,
ZIP

Which site's information is correct?

Please let me know if anyone knows something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take the second link as the official source of info/documentation for supported formats with our Model Derivative(Translation) service as it's actively maintained by our team behind the Model Derivative service and kept in sync with the latest of the API.

I will pass this discrepancy on to our team and appreciate for letting us know.

Comment: Thank you for answering. It was very helpful.