# Does Forge Support for inventor 2023?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-designautomation, autodesk-inventor

Currently im working on design automation of forge api. my inventor version is 2023
Does forge support inventor 2023? if does then what is engine name.

How to solve?
Forge inventor 2023 it is possible to do design automation using inventor 2023 in forge server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inventor 2023 is supported for more then year now by Design Automation. You can get the list of supported engines by calling /engines endpoint documented [here](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/engines-GET/).

Answer (score 1):

Please note that Forge is nowadays named [Autodesk Platform Services or APS](https://aps.autodesk.com/).

This question is answered by the StockOverflow thread on [What file formats does AutodeskForge support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53149819/what-file-formats-does-autodeskforge-support).

To repeat the answer, the official list is given by the APS list of [Supported Translation Formats](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations/).

Just like all other Autodesk CAD seed file modellers, at least the last three releases of the authoring tool are supported. In your case, this would cover Inventor 2024, Inventor 2023, and Inventor 2022.

I believe you can query the system for all supported engine names using the [GET Engines](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v2/reference/http/Engines-GET/) endpoint.